# Debugging external libs in Android

Tags: android, debugging, adt

I have several `.jar` files I want to reference into my Android project, and I have the sources for them. The point is that in order to build `.jar`'s from sources, I have to use Maven - the build process is pretty complicated, and as I am new to both Android and Maven, I am trying to reuse the script for building these libraries that was written before me, and do not add the sources directly.

So my intentions were pretty simple:

1. Build the `.class` files via Maven script
2. Compile `.jar` from these `.class` files via jar tool in the command line
3. Reference these libraries from my android project.

But as soon as I copy `.jar` files to the `libs` folder in the android project - I cannot add sources on them - and I cannot debug those.

Looks like this issue has been several times on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075453/the-jar-of-this-class-file-belongs-to-container-android-dependencies-which-doe) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064100/the-jar-of-this-class-file-blongs-to-container-android-2-0-1-which-does-not-allo). Still nothing works for me. `.properties` file doesn't seem to be recognized by Eclipse, when I go to Java Build Path - the path to the sources is marked as `(None)` and it is not modifiable, and if I reference the libraries like it was before ADT17 (adding a custom directory like `lib` with no `s` in the end, and referencing these jars as external libraries) - this fixes the debugging, but the compiler doesn't seem to include all the source code due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168841/unable-to-resolve-super-class)

I've read that should be fixed in ADT20, but I am using ADT21 and still no luck. Any usable workaround of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally did it! That still looks like a bug in ADT. The only solution I found is to reference the libs as it was before ADT17 (put them into the separate `lib` folder without 's', add them to build path, and mark the checkboxes in the `Configure Build Path -> Order and Export`).

The thing I was missing is actually marking the checkboxes - for some reason when you change anything in that dialog, the checkboxes are becoming unmarked. I guess I just didn't notice that...